# Problema con distribución Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Tengo un problema con el manejo d eFlexbox y Grid en una tarea (bastante sencilla) de recrear una página sin modificar el html (soy nuevo en html y css); al momento de ordenar los datos de un contenedor no logro equipararme a la figura de resultado porque no sé cómo aislar un "div" o sección de la caja.

Así se supone que debe de quedar:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es lo que he logrado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como no puedo modificar el html, no puedo hacer una caja que comprenda solamente los dos elementos que me interesan. No tengo idea de qué más hacer: por más que juego con columnas y filas no consigo el resultado esperado.

Gracias de antemano.

Atendiendo el error de no haber aportado el código, acá están el HTML(que no puede ser editado - de ahí que no pueda arreglarlo :/) y el CSS.

Mil disculpas por el caso.

```css
.about {
  margin-top: 2em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.about h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 2em;
}

.bio-info img {
  width: 200px;
}

.bio-info p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.contact {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 1em;
}

.contact *+* {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.contact-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-form input,
.contact-form textarea {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px 2em;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="about ">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Acerca de</h2>
    <div class="bio-info">

      <img src="images/logoBlanco.svg" alt="naldana logo">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis sint dolores culpa fugiat cumque est voluptatum, quibusdam voluptates corrupti saepe quaerat natus vel molestias earum obcaecati inventore quod libero distinctio tempora vero veniam
        incidunt nostrum! Totam corporis rerum maiores nesciunt?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      <form action="" class="contact-form">
        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Pedro Rodríguez">
        <label for="subject">Asunto</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Contratación">
        <label for="message">Mensaje</label>
        <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Contactar">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Por agrega tu código, para poder replicar tu ejercicio

Comment: Coloca el código por favor, así vamos a poder ayudarte mejor en tu problema. Pero a simple vista parece ser que no te toma el 100% del ancho. Pero como te digo, coloca el código y vamos a poder ayudarte mejor. Saludos.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: @Aprendiz He colocado el código. Estaba en el trabjo cuando forulé la pregunta, y, aunque no lo parezca, no se me ocurrió. xD

Answer (score 1):

Existen varios problemas en el código.

Cuando aplicas el valor *flex* a la propiedad *display*, todos los elementos definidos inmediatamente después de ellos se verán afectados. En el caso de la clase **.about**, estos sólo afectará a **.container**, así que no tiene mucho sentido utilizar *flex*.

Del mismo modo, tampoco podrías aplicar *flex* a la clase **.container** (por lo que se ve en la captura, tiene pinta de que también se ha indicado *display: flex;* para **.container**) porque, por defecto, alineará en tres columnas los tres elementos que están dentro de dicha clase: el `<h2>` y los dos `<div>` (**.bio-info** y **.contact**).

Una solución sería añadir otro `<div>` que incluyese dentro **.bio-info** y **.contact** para, en este caso sí, definir que *display: flex;*.

Por último, tampoco es necesario que utilices Flexbox para distribuir los elementos del formulario. Puedes meter un salto de línea (`<br>`) entre ellos o bien incluir cada bloque dentro de un `<div>`.

La cosa sería más o menos así:

```css
/* Alineamos el texto y lo pasamos a mayúsculas */
h2 { text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; }
/* Añadimos Flexbox para incluir como columnas a .bio-info y .contact */
.row { display: flex; }
/* Definimos un espacio por la derecha y definimos un ancho de columna, en este caso un 50% */
.bio-info { padding-right: 25px; width: 50%; }
/* Centramos la imagen definiendo márgenes automáticos a ambos lados, definimos un ancho para la imagen y un alto automático */
.bio-info img { display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 200px; height: auto; text-align: center; }
/* Definimos un espacio por la izquierda y definimos un ancho de columna, en este caso un 50% */
.contact { padding-left: 25px; width: 50%; }
/* Añadimos un margen bajo cada bloque de etiqueta + campo de formulario */
.contact-form-field { margin-bottom: 10px; }
/* Definimos la etiqueta de formulario como bloque para que ocupe toda a línea y añadimos un pequeño margen entre ella y el campo del formulario */
.contact-form-field label { display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; }
/* Definimos un ancho del 100% para los campos del formulario */
.contact-form-field input,
.contact-form-field textarea { display: block; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Acerca de</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="bio-info">
        <img src="images/logoBlanco.svg" alt="naldana logo">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis sint dolores culpa fugiat cumque est voluptatum, quibusdam voluptates corrupti saepe quaerat natus vel molestias earum obcaecati inventore quod libero distinctio tempora vero veniam
        incidunt nostrum! Totam corporis rerum maiores nesciunt?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <form action="" class="contact-form">
          <div class="contact-form-field">
            <label for="name">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Pedro Rodríguez">
          </div>
          <div class="contact-form-field">
            <label for="subject">Asunto</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Contratación">
          </div>
          <div class="contact-form-field">
            <label for="message">Mensaje</label>
            <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Contactar">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Ten en cuenta que dentro del ejemplo que puse, algunos valores son arbitrarios: el tamaño de la imagen, el ancho de **.bio-info** y **.contact** al 50%-50%, los márgenes (el espacio de 25px por la derecha de **.bio-info** y el 25px por la izquierda de **.contact** suman 50px) o los márgenes dentro de los campos del formulario. Puedes ajustarlos según necesidad.